# Is it possible to use jam instead of sugar to make a dough?

Tags: dough, cookies, milk, yogurt, jam

I followed this recipe to make a dough for cookies to dip in milk:

- 300g flour
- 1 egg
- 70g sugar
- 60g milk
- 50g butter
- 10g yeast

However I replaced sugar with jam (~100g) and butter with yogurt (~200g).

The result are cookies kind of fluffy, that took slightly more that twice the time in the oven (25m instead of 10m at 180C) and are chewy! And they do not dip really well in milk... I am not sure if I added too much yogurt or it is the pectin in the jam working against dipping. The fluffines might have been an overdosage of yeast.

Comment: I think that replacing sugar and butter with jam and yogurt just added a lot more moisture to the batter; it is normal that it will take more time to cook.

Comment: Your substitutions have likely more then doubled the amount of moisture in the recipe. Maybe experiment with reducing the amount of milk, yogurt and perhaps even how much the egg you use for the recipe.

Comment: Curious whether you have ever made these cookies without the substitutions. And if so, did *those* dip well in milk? Other commentators' remarks about more moisture taking longer to cook are very believable, but I question whether cookies leavened with yeast would ever be good for dipping. Your observations, "kind of fluffy ... and are chewy! And they do not dip really well in milk..." sound like consequences of leavening with yeast instead of the more usual (for cookies) baking powder or baking soda.

Comment: Using jam would be not dissimilar to using thick syrup (which some recipes use).....

Answer (score 4):

Almost any substitution is about making a trade-off and understanding the ratios involved. In this case replacing 70g sugar and 50g of butter with 100g of jam and 200g of yogurt you both increase the moisture and remove the sugar crystals from the texture. During the [***creaming process***](https://www.seriouseats.com/2015/12/cookie-science-creaming-butter-sugar.html) (where sugars and fats are blended) the sugar crystals play a vital role in creating air pockets that will determine the final texture.

> [**Why Do I Cream Butter, and What Happens If I Don't?**](http://Why%20Do%20I%20Cream%20Butter,%20and%20What%20Happens%20If%20I%20Don't?)
>
> In pastry-speak, this process is described as "mechanical leavening":
>   physically cramming air into a dough so that it'll puff up in the oven
>   like a hot-air balloon. Google around, and that's what you'll be told,
>   time and again. Creaming adds air. Air is fluffy. Fluffy is good. Good
>   is great. Yay, cookies!

The yeast almost certainly made up for a lack of 'mechanical leaving' that didn't occur because of the jam, which lacked the crystalline structure granulated sugar would have provided.

If one substitutes enough elements of a cookie recipe at what point does it stop being a cookie? Your own question answers itself that it is *possible* to replace A & B with C & D. It even looks like you created something quite good (I'm tempted to try it out), but is it still "a cookie" or something else all together? But then there is the whole "dipping it in milk" goal. This creation is more likely to breakdown in milk (as you have observed) and short of putting it between two graham crackers, probably always will be.

Comment: The "cookies" don't break down in milk, but they don't absorb any. My idea of cookies for milk is that they should get soaked, right? I increased the dosage of yogurt and jam so that the equival of fat and sugar would stay somewhat the same, I think the yogurt was closer to 125g however, not 200g. Anyway while doing the dough I kept adding flour until it would stop being sticky, so maybe moisture is not a problem? Another error I made was using beer yeast instead of yeast for cakes, not sure if that also contributed to it.

Comment: I might have also overstated the chewy part; They definitely require more teeth and if you want to take a bite you have to pull because of their elasticity, but they are not gums!